# Reusing authentication state between Jasmine blocks

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

My app requires users to sign in by submitting a form. I wonder what is the best place to do it in my tests. I came up with some options:

1. sign-in in `beforeEach` block (and signout in `afterEach` block)
2. sign-in in `beforeAll` block of every `describe` (and signout in the last `afterAll` of every `describe`)

   ```
     describe('APP', function () {
       describe('FEATURE 1', function () { 
         beforeAll(function () {
          //sign in
         });
         afterAll(function () {
          //sign out
         });
        //...
       });
     });
   ```
3. sign-in once for the whole test run in `beforeAll` of main `describe`

   ```
     describe('MY APP', function () {
       beforeAll(function () {
          //sign in
       });

       describe('my feature 1', function () { 
        //...
       });
     });
   ```

**Number 1** is the slowest, **Number 2** is faster and **Number 3** is the fastest, but you are required to have a single entry point for your test runner - not ideal. So which do think is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of different things.

The best practice is closing your browser after EACH test case and it will definitely be the slowest way to run your test. But you will achieve the most clear and the most fair tests. Sure, you can use selenium grid and paralleling your tests and this will be definitely not so long as you expect.

Sometimes you have an application, which logic is not so much dependent on each other and you will probably want to run UI tests into the pre-commit hook for not breaking anything into the branch. Then the approach n.3 will be not so bad (the only thing you should know is what cookies, session vars and other artifacts you should delete in browser after each test).

Anyway that's up to you, but a common and the really BEST practice is opening a clear new browser on every test.